# Удалить из вещественного массива элементы, расположенные между максимумом и минимумом массива

Tags: массивы, javascript

Код рабочий:

```
var str = "5 2 1 5 6 2 55.2 1";
var arr = str.split(' ');
var min  =  Math.min.apply(Math, arr);
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
var reg = RegExp(min + " .*? " + max);
str = str.replace(reg, min + " " + max);
alert(str)
```

Перерыл литературы, не понимаю, как работает `str.replace`.

Comment: а в чем проблема ? 5 6 2 удаляется

Comment: Как я понял, reg заменяет min + " " + max в строке str, но как

Comment: если взять числа 5 2  5 6 2 55.2 10 1

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вообще эта задача без регекспа решается, `Array.indexOf()` - позиции, потом смотрим, какая позиция больше, и делаем что-то типа

```
arr.splice(minPos+1,maxPos-minPos-1)
```